# Dependency Injection if service exists

Tags: 8, services, dependency-injection

Is there any way to use dependency injection in a conditional way, i.e. only if a service exists similar to \Drupal::hasService().

I have a created a service in module A and in module B I have an EventSubscriber that should use the service from module A, but only if present of course.

Static I would do sth. like:
    if (\Drupal::hasService('module_a.my_service')) {
      \Drupal::service('module_a.my_service')->mymethod();
    }

Is there any possibility to do this when injecting the service?

Comment: If it depends on it, when would it not be available?

Comment: When the module A is not installed. It's optional. I have a couple of helper services in module A that are all optional, e.g. debugging, logging and notification functionalities.

Comment: Just add some logic to your static `create` method which checks `$container->has(‘service’)`, and pass null to the constructor for those that are missing. Then check the service is an instance of the class you expect it to be before you use it

Comment: But I don’t recommend that approach because it anchors to the wrong thing. Dependency injection doesn’t really work as a concept if the dependencies are optional. There are probably better practice ways to structure your code to base the decision on whether the module is installed or not, which is the real trigger, and not on whether a service exists

Comment: I see, you might be right, I'll check if I can restructure the code. Maybe additional submodules which implement the service calls and do not perform any check are better.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to handle this situation is for your Module B to define a default, stub service with the same type signature (ie, `Interface`) as the one you need).  Use that in the YAML.  Then, in your Module A, you can [alter the service](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) to the one that the module provides.

That said, I do agree with the comments that you may be bypassing one of the benefits of DI, and creating a tight coupling between your two modules.  Read the linked article to see when it is appropriate.  Core uses it for the language and workspaces subsystems.